# Com port is not working in java

Tags: java, serial-port

i followed some tutorials and i found that code but its not returning port names.I check every detail about com ports but found nothing. Also in my device manager com ports are hidden and im unable to unhide them.
please guide me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    System.out.println("SELECT PORT");

    int i=0;
    for(SerialPort port : ports)
        System.out.println(i++ +  ": " + port.getSystemPortName());
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = s.nextInt();
    SerialPort serialPort = ports[a - 1];
    if(serialPort.openPort())
    {
        System.out.print("PORT OPEN");

    }
    else {
        System.out.print("PORT NOT OPEN\n");
    }

    serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
    PrintWriter p =new PrintWriter( serialPort.getOutputStream());
    System.out.print("WELCOME TO CONTROLL SYSTEM\n");
    // System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really have COM ports (physical or virtual)?

Comment: yes when i click on show hidden devices in device manager it show com ports